# Lua timer - creating a timer to execute a function every X seconds

Tags: lua, timer, nodemcu

Following instructions on https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/tmr/#tobjcreate

I am trying to create a timer in my Lua script which will execute a function every 10 seconds. Sample timer from my script:

```
mytimer = tmr.create
mytimer:register(10000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, my_function() end)
mytimer:start()
```

When I execute my script I'm getting a syntax error:

```
'=' expected near 'mytimer'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I get `')' expected near 'end'`.

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of asking here, a good starting point would have been to compare your code vs the code example from the documentation you linked:

```
local mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer:register(5000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function (t) print("expired"); t:unregister() end)
mytimer:start()
```

Example: `local mytimer = tmr.create()`

You      `mytimer = tmr.create`

You're missing the call operator here. Not making `mytimer` local is bad practice but won't give you an error.

Example: `mytimer:register(5000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function (t) print("expired"); t:unregister() end)`

You:  `mytimer:register(10000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, my_function() end)`

I don't know what `my_function` is. The end doesn't belong here unless you're defining a function in place. then it should look like in the example. Your version would only be ok without the `end` and if `my_function()` would return a function value.

`function (t) print("expired"); t:unregister() end` defines an anonymous function. This resolves to a function value that is used as an argument for the callback parameter of the register function.

You could also do it like:

```
local callback = function (t) print("expired"); t:unregister() end
mytimer:register(5000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, callback)
```

Anything else is described in the manual.